# Pivot strings in SQl on Identifier

Tags: sql, pivot

I have two columns in sql

```
        ID      Perils

        1        PES
        1        PEA
        2        PAL
        2        PWH
```

I wanted a query which can get me

```
        ID      Perils

        1        PES+PEA
        2        PAL+PWH
```

Hence concatenating string with delimitor '+' by pivoting on ID

Answer (score 1):

Group by ID column and concatenate the Perils column.  Now the aggregate for doing this is DB-specific.  For MySQL, it would be:

```
select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Perils) as Perils
from theTable
group by ID
```

the method for Oracle is listagg().

Comment: What about Sql Server, I am doing in SSMS

Comment: SSMS you can use FOR XML PATH like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server